# Issue importing spreadsheet with column null in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a strange issue while importing file from spreadsheet to our sql database table. If first row of any column is null then the whole column reflect as null in the table even if there is data in the 5th or 10th row for that column.  Did any one face this issue while importing .xls data to sql server database?  Again if the first row of that column is not null then the data will get imported properly.

Comment: Are you using a pre-built package, or the import wizard?

Comment: I'm using data flow in ssis selecting source assistant (.xls file) and destination assistant (sql database table) @tab Alleman

Comment: Excel is horrible for imports, but I would be willing to wager your problem is that the import is thinking the data type is not what you expect. When importing Excel, the [fill in a bad word] thing only looks at the first few lines even though last time the column type was int or date. It will change it to nvarchar and any time any int or date comes up it will null it out. A possible solution to include IMEX=1 in connection string but that doesn't always work either.

Comment: @KeithL The data which we get is govt data and it comes on spreadsheet format only. any help on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is that is when exporting Excel files with mixed data types column it will replace non dominant types by null.**

This cannot be solved in a direct method, but based on my experience there are two workaround that can gives good results.

1. Adding a dummy first row that contains random text values like `abc`, and adding `;IMEX=1` to the connectionstring, this will force excel to read the data type from the first row and it will read all data as `Text`
2. Read Excel File without Headers *(in the ConnectionString you should have `HDR=NO`)*. also add `IMEX=1` to the connectionstring, Write the Columns name in the `Excel Source` manually, Skip the first Row *(Which contains the columns headers)* using Script Component.

---

*Note: Importing data from excel using OLEDB or Ace (used in Excel connection manager) provider doesn't give 100% results, so these workarounds are to minimize the errors as much as possible*

Comment: Thanks @Hadi , I’m going to try on Monday when I’m going back to work . Thanks for your helpful suggestions. I will let you know brother ...